# Proper way to insert a hyperlink in a text control

Tags: cocoa, hyperlink, nstextview

ALL,

I am looking for a way to properly insert a hyperlink into the NSTextView.

Trying to do that I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1487/_index.html) link which explains how to make it work. However trying to set the following text:

`abc http://www.google.com`

I failed to do so with the following code:

```
std::string test = "abc \"http://www.google.com\"";
int pos1 = test.find( "http://" );
std::string temp1 = test.substr( 0, pos1 );
[tv setString:temp1];
std::string url_text = test.substr( pos1 );
NSMutableAttributedString string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
NSURL *url_obj = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
[string appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString hyperlinkFromString:url_text withURL:url_obj];
[[tv textStorage] setAttributedString: string];
[string release];
```

however, the underlining and the blue foreground starts from the very first position of the text, i.e. the whole text is underlined, and not just a link.

So looking further I found I can just simply do [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/setAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled:). But neither setting the above string, nor trying to type the link gives me the appropriate visible representation of the link - blue and underlined font.

So now my questions are:

Is it possible to do an automatic parsing of the hyperlink in NSTextView when I both set the text and type the text manually?
If not, what is the problem with the code above and why I see the link on all string and not just the text of the link?

I hope I will not need to do any manual work and everything will be automatic.

Thank you and sorry for such a big post.

Comment: Does automatic link detection work if you type a link followed by a space?

Comment: @Willeke, should it start with "www" or "http://www"?

Comment: @Willeke, should it start with "www" or "http://www"? OK, I just tried to type either "www.google.com " or "http://www.google.com ". Nothing happened. The text stays as text and it didn't become a link. Documentation says it's 10.5+ and I'm on 10.6... Sorry, 5 min expired. ;-)

Comment: If you switched on "Smart Links" in the xib or switched on "automaticLinkDetectionEnabled" programmatically, typed links should be detected. Programmatically insterted links can be detected with one of the checkTextIn… methods of NSTextView.

Comment: @Willeke, yes did just that and it works. The docs from Apple sucks though... ;-)